# Grid system not working as expected in a Vuetify v-footer

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to get all of my links in three columns in my footer with the copyright line below that. However, my copyright line is showing up in a phantom fourth column and it overlaps the third column if the screen width gets too small. If I use the same layout in my content section, I get the three columns.

Here is my footer component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-footer color="primary lighten-1" padless>
      <v-row justify="center">
        <v-col cols=4>
          <div class="my-1">
            <v-btn color="white" text rounded>
              Contact Us
            </v-btn>
          </div>
          <div class="my-1">
            <v-btn color="white" text rounded>
              Contact Us
            </v-btn>
          </div>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols=4>
          <div class="my-1">
            <v-btn color="white" text rounded>
              Data Sources
            </v-btn>
          </div>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols=4>
          <div class="my-1">
            <v-btn color="white" text rounded>
              Browse Maps
            </v-btn>
          </div>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>

      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <p class="text-center grey--text text--lighten-2">Copyright 2020, </p>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-footer>
  </div>
<template>
```

On a possibly related note, why do I have to wrap each button in a div with a my-? class to get the buttons to stack vertically.

Edit:

I am using Vuetify v2.2.11.

Here is a screenshot of what it is doing:

[image]

Here is what I want:

[image]

My buttons that are within the same column are showing up side/side unless I either wrap them in the my-? classed div or there is not enough room in the column to display them side/side. I would like them stacked on top of each other in every screen size. And of course I only want the three columns for my buttons

Comment: Can you say me your version of vuetify? I mean it will be version conflict.

Comment: you don't need to wrap each button. Can you share a screen shot of your desired output? What do you mean stack vertically?

Comment: Editing the question to respond to both comments, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `v-row` only works as expected if wrapped in a `v-container`.
Add a `<v-container fluid>` around your v-rows and it should work just fine. Fluid is described as "Removes viewport maximum-width size breakpoints", thus removing the horizontal padding.

The whole thing would look like this in the end:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-footer color="primary lighten-1" padless>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row class="text-center">
          <v-col cols="4">
            <div class="my-1">
              <v-btn color="white" text rounded>
                Contact Us
              </v-btn>
            </div>
            <div class="my-1">
              <v-btn color="white" text rounded>
                Contact Us
              </v-btn>
            </div>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="4">
            <div class="my-1">
              <v-btn color="white" text rounded>
                Data Sources
              </v-btn>
            </div>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="4">
            <div class="my-1">
              <v-btn color="white" text rounded>
                Browse Maps
              </v-btn>
            </div>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>

        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12">
            <p class="text-center grey--text text--lighten-2">
              Copyright 2020,
            </p>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I had tried wrapping the v-footer in a v-container, but that was too high up the food chain.